# C# случайные числа

Tags: c#

Почему при выполнении данного кода все элементы массива Jarr имеют одинаковую длину,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] Jarr = new int[10][];
            for (int i = 0; i < Jarr.Length; i++)
            {
                Jarr[i] = new int[new Random().Next(10)];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Jarr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Jarr[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ",Jarr[i][j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
```

а при выполнении этого разную?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] Jarr = new int[10][];
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < Jarr.Length; i++)
            {
                Jarr[i] = new int[rand.Next(10)];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Jarr.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Jarr[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ",Jarr[i][j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В первом случае вы создаете новый экземпляр `Random` на каждой итерации, который инициализируется системным временем. Системные часы не успевают обновить свое значение за время выполнения цикла, поэтому все экземляры `Random` инициализируются одним и тем же начальным значением ‒ оно и возвращается. Иными словами, каждый раз выбирается первое значение одной и той же псевдослучайной последовательности.

Во втором случае вы используете один экземпляр `Random` и генерируете последовательность псевдослучайных чисел, в которой каждое число встречается равновероятно (почти).

Из [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from
> the system clock and has finite
> resolution. As a result, different
> Random objects that are created in
> close succession by a call to the
> default constructor will have
> identical default seed values and,
> therefore, will produce identical sets
> of random numbers.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение!

Comment: Интересная штука. Честно говоря, я был уверен, что ГСЧ инициализируется системным временем, но с какой-то большой точностью - чуть ли не до такта процессора...

Comment: В .NET Core данной проблемы нет, `Random()` берёт случайный seed, не привязанный ко времени.