# Многократная генерация паролей

Tags: c#, генерация-случайных-данных

Есть код, генерирующий пароли. Мне надо, чтобы он генерировал их пока я не закрою софт или пока не выполнится условие.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string s0, st, s1;
     s0 = "";
     Random rnd = new Random();
     int n;
     st = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
     for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
     {
          n = rnd.Next(0, 61);
          s1 = st.Substring(n, 1);
          s0 += s1;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(s0);
     Console.ReadKey();                                                                      
}
```

Comment: `st.Substring(n, 1)` вполне можно заменить на `st[n]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ну так и сделайте цикл.

```
string s0, st, s1;
Random rnd = new Random();
int n;
while (ваше_условие) 
{ 
    s0 = "";
    st = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        n = rnd.Next(0, 61);
        s1 = st.Substring(n, 1);
        s0 += s1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s0);
}
```

И пара замечаний

1. Обратите внимание, что обхект `rnd` создается один раз. Если сделать его создание в теле цикла `while` то никакой рандомности вы не получите. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/234407/c-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/234410) можете почитать почему.
2. Вместо конкатенаций строк при формировании пароля `s0 += s1` лучше использовать [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
3. Магическое число 61 в строке `n = rnd.Next(0, 61);` видимо длина строки `st` - 1. Что будет, если длина исходного алфавита изменится? Поэтому лучше написать `st.Length`

Comment: Можно уточнить чем лучше StringBuilder? Или и Вы имеете ввиду сразу сделать строку на нужную длину и заполнять ее символами?

Comment: @AndreyGolikov, строки в c# неизменяемые, таким образом когда выполняется _s0 += s1_ создается **еще** одна строка. StringBuilder позволяет обойтись одной строкой, так как внутри себя работает со строками напрямую

Comment: @Donil пробовал с вайл но не знал куда его засунуть))

Comment: откатил вашу последнюю правку, т.к. `Random.Next` не включает верхнюю границу в возвращаемые значения.

Comment: @rdorn, согласен. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Все верно, поместите в цикл свой код. В условие рекомендую булевую переменную поставить или просто пропишите true и сделайте бесконечным.
Только я бы дополнил код задержкой, потому что он будет генерироваться бесконечно. Не помню как на шарпе, это грамотно сделать..